# Using a table of integrals for solving these integrals

Tags: integration

I'm having trouble matching these integrals to their corresponding integral in the table of integrals.

I have this integral:

$$\int_0^2 x^2*\sqrt{4-x^2}$$

Which one of these matches?

I have this integral:

$$u*\sqrt{a+bu}du = \frac{2}{15b^2} * (ebu-2a)(a+bu)^{\frac{3}{2}} + C$$

but wolfram gives me that the answer is $\pi$. Am I using the wrong match? It looks like it since number 54 (in the table below) has a + sign whereas this has a minus sign. Perhaps number 113 is a better match? But this form doesn't 100% correspond...

If I use the integral form:

$$\int u \sqrt{a+bu}$$

Can I use $u = x^2$, $a = 4$, and $b = -1$?

I also have this integral:

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{2y^2-3}}{y^2}$$

I am totally lost on this one. Nothing even looks close?

Here are the tables that are in question:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: For the first integral, write $x=2\cos{u}$ (or $\sin$ maybe).

Comment: that will give me $4 - 2cosu^2$ or $4 - 4cos^2u$ or 4(1-cos^2u) or 4sinu right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the table does not work is because it is in terms of $du$, but you are trying to use the substitution $u=x^2$ without converting the $dx$  into $du$ first. If we try to convert this into $du$ using $dx=\frac{1}{2\sqrt u}dx$, we find that:

$$\int_0^2 x^2\sqrt{4-x^2}dx=\int_0^4 \frac{u\sqrt{4-u}}{2\sqrt u}du=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^4 \sqrt{\frac{4-u}{u}}du$$

Now, this doesn't match anything on your table, so I think we should try a different u-substitution. Since we have $\sqrt{4-x^2}$, let's try $x=2\sin u$ since that will get rid of the square root. Remember to substitute $dx=2\cos u$:

$$\int_0^2 x^2\sqrt{4-x^2}dx=\int_0^{\pi/2} 4\sin^2 u\cdot 2\cos u\cdot 2\cos udu=\int_0^{\pi/2} 16(\sin u\cos u)^2du$$

Remember that $\sin u\cos u=\frac{\sin 2u}{2}$:

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} 16(\sin u\cos u)^2du=\int_0^{\pi/2} 4\sin^2(2u)du$$

Let $v=2u$:

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} 4\sin^2(2u)du=\int_0^\pi 2\sin^2vdv$$

Remember that $2\sin^2v=1-\cos(2v)$:

$$\int_0^\pi (1-\cos(2v))dv=v-\frac{\sin(2v)}{2}^\pi_0=(\pi-0)-(0-0)=\pi$$

Comment: Is there anything in my tables that correspond to your method?

Comment: @Jwan622 Well, once you do the first u-substitution and get down to $\int_0^{\pi/2} 16\sin^2\cos^2 udu$, you can use Rule#86 to reduce the integral. I just chose to go a different path at that point instead of using the table.